# How to read from pointer in python?

Tags: python, cheat-engine

I'm using cheat engine to find a multipointer that leads to an address that has value of list of entities. I found said multipointer, but I have no clue how to read it using python.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example on how to read from a process, on Windows, using the Windows API and [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). Doesn't require external packages / modules.

Error and argument handling is minimal.

Basically:

- Open the process using [`OpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) for address space read. This only requires the process PID.
- Read a whole page from the process, using [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory). You'll need to offset in the returned buffer if you want something within the page.
- Demonstrate how to "cast" from `bytes` to, in this instance, `DWORD`. You can of course use another `ctypes` numerous types instead of `DWORD` (which is defined as `ctypes.c_uint32` iirc).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes as wt

# Windows API


kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

OpenProcess = kernel32.OpenProcess
OpenProcess.restype = wt.HANDLE
OpenProcess.argtypes = (
    wt.DWORD,  # DWORD dwAccess
    wt.BOOL,  # BOOL bInheritHandle
    wt.DWORD,  # DWORD ProcessId
)

ReadProcessMemory = kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
ReadProcessMemory.restype = wt.BOOL
ReadProcessMemory.argtypes = (
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # HANDLE hProcess
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # LPCVOID lpBaseAddress
    ctypes.c_void_p,  # LPVOID  lpBuffer
    ctypes.c_size_t,  # SIZE_T  nSize
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_size_t)  # SIZE_T  *lpNumberOfBytesRead
)

CloseHandle = kernel32.CloseHandle
CloseHandle.restype = wt.BOOL
CloseHandle.argtypes = (wt.HANDLE,)


def read_from_process(base_addr: int, pid: int) -> bytes:
    """Read a whole page from the given process.

    Args:
        base_addr: The base address to read from. This address is always rounded down to a 4KB page boundary.
        pid: the pid of the process.

    Raises:
        OsError: either the process couldn't be opened or there was an error reading from the process.

    Returns:
        The content of the page read from the process as a bytes instance.
    """
    # size of a page, in bytes.
    page_size = 4096

    # base of the page.
    base_addr &= 0xfffffffffffff000

    # open the process for address space reading.
    h_proc = OpenProcess(0x8 | 0x10,  # PROCESS_VM_OPERATION | PROCESS_VM_READ
                         False,
                         pid)
    if h_proc == 0:
        # couldn't open the process; either wrong pid or not enough rights to open it.
        raise ctypes.WinError()

    # read from the process.
    buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b'', page_size)
    nobr = ctypes.c_size_t(0)
    ret_val = ReadProcessMemory(h_proc, base_addr, buffer, page_size, ctypes.byref(nobr))
    if ret_val == 0:
        CloseHandle(h_proc)
        raise ctypes.WinError()

    CloseHandle(h_proc)
    return buffer.raw


def main():
    pid = 9708
    base_addr = 0x7ff6947c0000

    buffer = read_from_process(base_addr, pid)

    # example how to read 2 DWORDs (unsigned 32-bit) from the bytes buffer.
    dword_buffer = (wt.DWORD * 2).from_buffer_copy(buffer)

    # print some bytes from the bytes instance.
    print(buffer[0:8])

    # print DWORDs.
    print(f"{dword_buffer[0]:08x}")
    print(f"{dword_buffer[1]:08x}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Test on the base of a PE module:

```
b'MZ\x90\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00'
00905a4d
00000003
```